# Swagger ui url with parameters

Tags: html, swagger, swagger-ui

How to pass base url in the form `http://localhost:3000/resources/api/?key=aslkdajd1323121lklakskdl` to swagger ui ?

I was able to access `http://localhost:3000/resources/api` but when I add auth filter and pass key, it says, `Unauthorized`.

Using swagger 1.X

Pre-populating the parameter through apiKeyauthorization in index.html did not help, but when I type in the key in UI, it worked. Unable to understand the reason for this. Hope someone can help me make sense out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this swagger 2.0 file (use http://studio.restlet.com to downgrade to version 1.2) :

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "title": "Todo App"
    },
    "host": "localhost:3000",
    "schemes": [
    "http"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/resources/api": {
            "post": {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "key",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "key",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful response"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also help me find json file related to my path ? I was making necessary changes in index.html page of swagger ui as of now as I could figure out where the json file was. Also if it was that I must create the json file, please help me on how to redirect my servlet to json rather than html docx ? Note: I am configuring swagger on my application rather than maintaining json file to populate swagger ui.

Comment: Can you confirm this response helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding

`window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("key", yourKeyValue, "query"));`

in the SwaggerUI constructor function

`window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({ . . .`

right before the statement

`window.swaggerUi.load()`

Answer (score 0):

You just need get the parameter from the url with javscript. In the file "index.html", under swagger-ui/dist folder, add something like this to get your key:

```
var key = window.location.search.match(/key=([^&]+)/);
```

You can see a simple example in my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/ScalaSoft/f5051ed6753433e903abdb640326e6c4).

Comment: This Gist doesn’t exist.